# PDO safe insertion/reading with explode function

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

[Database Structure Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bavG.png)

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Database Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

    <div id='box1'>
        <h1>Insert Info Here</h1>
            <hr/>
            <form action="" method="post">
            <label>Client name :</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Name"/><br /><br />
            <label>Client surname :</label>
            <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Surname"/><br /><br />
            <label>Client email :</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Email"/><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />
            </form>
    </div>

    <?php
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
        echo '</pre>';

        include_once "connect_bdd.php"; 
        include_once "fonctions_bdd.php";
        $bdd=info_bdd();
        $dbh=connectBase($bdd);


    ?>

</body>

</html>
```

here is my main html code, where I'm trying to ask/make entries in PDO to my database

```
<?php

function info_bdd(){
$bdd="mydb";
return($bdd);
}


function connectBase($bdd){


//base locale
$user="root";$pass="";$dbh="erreur";
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$bdd, $user, $pass, array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    }
catch (PDOException $e){print "Erreur !: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";die();}
return $dbh;

}
function closeConnectBase(){$dbh = null;}
?>
```

this is the PHP file (connect_bdd.php) that connects to the database

```
<?php
include_once "connect_bdd.php"; 

function ask($req,$param,$bdd){
//echo "<hr>count tbl param = ".count($param)."<br>req = ".$req;
$dbh=connectBase($bdd);
//Préparer la requête
$prep = $dbh->prepare($req);
//Associer des valeurs aux place holders
$count_prep=0;
foreach($param as $key=>$val){
    $count_prep++;
    $parametre=explode("µ",$val);
    switch($parametre[0]){
        case "str":$prep->bindValue($count_prep, $parametre[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);break;
        case "int":$prep->bindValue($count_prep, $parametre[1], PDO::PARAM_INT);break;
        case "bool":$prep->bindValue($count_prep, $parametre[1], PDO::PARAM_BOOL);break;
        case "null":$prep->bindValue($count_prep, $parametre[1], PDO::PARAM_NULL);break;
        default:$prep->bindValue($count_prep, $parametre[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);break;
    }
}
//Compiler et exécuter la requête
$prep->execute();
//Récupérer toutes les données retournées
$rep = $prep->fetchAll();
//Clore la requête préparée
$prep->closeCursor();
$prep = NULL;
closeConnectBase();
return $rep;
}

function make($req){
try{
$dbh=connectBase(info_bdd("name"));
$prep = $dbh->prepare($req);
$prep->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
// exit ($e -> getMessage());
}
}

?>
```

And this is the php file (fonctions_bdd.php) that contains both the ask and make classes.

I found both of the extra php files while doing research, but now I'm stuck and can't find a way to use the explode function to insert into and extract from the database (I'll also add the CSS file in there too, just in case). Thanks in advance for your help !

```
#box1{width:200;
float:left;
border-radius:8px;
font-family: Arial;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
padding: 10px 40px 25px;
margin-top: 70px;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you supply a sample data you're trying to `explode` and your db schema to see how we will implement the insert,select etc.

Comment: @Cemal here are some fillers for the form : name : John , surname : Doe , email : jdoe@gmail.com, I've also uploaded a screenshot of the database (only one table - users with [idusers - auto increment; firstname; surname; email])

Comment: So far I haven't been able to see what you're trying to explode.

Comment: if it's only insert using PDO, there are lots of stuff around. I don't think you need to be using `explode` anywhere(according to these codes you have supplied)

Comment: Why do you need to be so specific when binding? PDO can usually do a good-enough bind without all that coaching.